# How to add external library in classpath?

Tags: java

I have a folder that contains these java files: Main, TableManager, CustomFileWriter, CustomFileReader plus the external library commons-lang3-3.0.jar.I'm trying to compile the Main.java with this command

```
javac -cp commons-lang3-3.0.jar Main.java
```

but it says cannot find symbol

```
TableManager table = new TableManager()
```

I create an instance of TableManager in Main class. Without the external library and compiling with just javac Main.java works fine. How can I fix this. I need the external library for the StringUtils. I'm not using frameworks. Just text editor and running to terminal.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: try `javac -cp .;commons-lang3-3.0.jar Main.java`, for windows/replace the semi-colon with a full colon on linux

Comment: TableManager class is just a normal java class. It reads and writes to file.

Comment: @Richard Jones the command works and now compiled but I got this error while running the app. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils

Comment: @DanielBristol to run use `java -cp .;commons-lang3-3.0.jar Main`

Comment: @Richard Jones thanks. It works!

Answer (score 2):

To compile a Java file and include a `Jar` file, enter the following command line:

```
  javac -cp jar-file Main.java
```

For multiple `JAR` files, separate the `jar-files` with semicolons `;`, with the following command line:

```
  javac -cp jar-file1;jar-file2;jar-file3 Main.java
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the path, not just the jar name, like

`javac -cp c:\home\ann\public_html\classes\compute.jar
    engine\ComputeEngine.java`

You can check it in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/compiling.html).

Answer (score 0):

To compile a class (on windows) with a jar in the same direcory use:

```
javac -cp .;myjar.jar MyClass.java
```

To then run the class you can use:

```
java -cp .;myjar.jar MyClass
```

NOTE: on linux you will need to replace `;` with `:`

Answer (score 0):

The "-cp" Option overwrites your classpath. So in order to successfully compile and run your java-app, you have to add the path of your Main.class file and the external library as arguments. Here the "." is the relative path to your Main.class file and commons-lang3-3.0.jar the relative path to the external library. Under Windows it is sometimes necessarry to use quotes.

To compile:

```
javac -cp ".;commons-lang3-3.0.jar" Main.java
```

To run:

```
java -cp ".;commons-lang3-3.0.jar" Main
```