# Running selenium testng executable jar is failing

Tags: java, windows, selenium, testng, executable-jar

I have written a simple Selenium + TestNG maven project (say, in directory `I:\Projects\`) using Java in Eclipse IDE, when I right click the project and run `testng.xml` file able to launch the Chrome browser
I have now exported this project as 'Runnable JAR file' and saved the jar on Desktop (`C:\Users\Programmer\Desktop`).

Now,

1. If I run the saved executable jar from my project directory and double click the jar, able to launch the Chrome browser, that is,
   `I:\Projects>java -jar "C:\Users\Programmer\Desktop\runnable.jar"`, but
2. If I save the executable jar from desktop unable to launch the browser, that is `C:\Users\Programmer\Desktop>java -jar runnable.jar`

My simple selenium code,

```
public class GoogleSearch {

WebDriver driver;

@Test
public void launchBrowser() {
    String PWD = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    System.out.println(">>>>>>" + PWD);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", PWD + "\\lib\\chromedriver");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    search.sendKeys("Selenium monk");
}

@Test
public void tearDown() {
    if (driver != null) {
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
}
```

**Project directory structure..**

[image]

> I understood like, when I am running from Desktop, jar is unable to
> find the chromedriver in lib folder.?  If yes, how to make it
> work.?

What else is I am missing here?

Comment: You need to put lib in classpath

Comment: @Vipin that would be great if you can share a piece of code with the user. So that user will be able to understand the answer properly. :)

Comment: For example see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35573468/how-to-add-external-library-in-classpath

Comment: @Vipin: Oops I missed to mention that, I have tried set classpath="<dir_path_of_lib\\*>" but didn't work. Thank you for response.

Comment: There must be something wrong in the way you tried this, update question with what you did.

Comment: Could you please share the class file content present in API.RunTestngFromJar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved on my own, since the problem was, "when I am running from Desktop, jar is unable to find the chromedriver in lib folder."

I need to set the chrome driver as part of environment variables, and I have updated the chrome driver property by reading the env var, `System.getenv("chrome_driver_path");`

After which my problem resolved.

Thank you all for those who took your time to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

When your jar is on the desktop, try to run this (assuming your are running under C:\Users\you\Desktop),

```
java -cp runnable.jar;path-to-your-proj\lib\* org.testng.TestNG path-to-your-proj/testng.xml -Duser.dir=path-to-your-proj
```